# Find Fixed Plane of 4D Simple Rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations

I have a 4D simple rotation matrix $M$ with angle $\theta$. Is there a way to find the plane that is fixed by M?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your matrix $M$ should have eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $2$.
Find the two eigenvectors.  They form a basis for the plane that is fixed by $M$.